# What is an efficient way of parsing a string of single-character commands, each optionally followed by an integer repeat count?

Tags: rust

I am implementing a robot that takes orders like `L` (turn left), `R` (turn right) and `M` (move forward). These orders may be augmented with a quantifier like `M3LMR2` (move 3 steps, turn left, move one step, turn face). This is the equivalent of `MMMLMRR`.

I coded the robot structure that can understand the following enum:

```
pub enum Message {                                                                                                                                                            
    TurnLeft(i8),                                                                                                                                                             
    TurnRight(i8),                                                                                                                                                            
    MoveForward(i8),                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

`Robot::execute(&mut self, orders: Vec<Message>)` is doing its job correctly.

Now, I am struggling to write something decent for the string parsing, juggling with `&str`, `String`, `char` and unsafe slicings because tokens can be 1 or more characters.

I have tried regular expression matching (almost worked), but I really want to tokenize the string:

```
fn capture(orders: &String, start: &usize, end: &usize) -> Message {
    unsafe {
        let order = orders.get_unchecked(start..end);
        // …
    };

    Message::TurnLeft(1) // temporary
}

pub fn parse_orders(orders: String) -> Result<Vec<Message>, String> {
    let mut messages = vec![];
    let mut start: usize = 0;
    let mut end: usize = 0;

    while end < orders.len() && end != start {
        end += 1;

        match orders.get(end) {
            Some('0'...'9') => continue,
            _ => {
                messages.push(capture(&orders, &start, &end));
                start = end;
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(messages)
}
```

This doesn't compile and is clumsy.

The idea is to write a parser that turn the order string into a vector of `Message`:

```
let messages = parse_order("M3LMR2");
println!("Messages => {:?}", messages);
// would print
// [Message::MoveForward(3), Message::TurnLeft(1), Message::MoveForward(1), Message::TurnRight(2)]
```

What would be the efficient/elegant way for doing that?

Comment: This is a pretty broad problem, you might want to narrow it down a bit; in addition, you probably want to be using `u8` instead of `i8` in the `Message` enum.

Comment: Thank for your comments, I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: you can't ask in a question how to write a parser, there is very big book that doesn't cover this question. As you format code is simple why not make something simple like a machine state ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this very simply with an iterator, using `parse` and some basic `String` processing:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
enum Message {                                                                                                                                                            
    TurnLeft(u8),                                                                                                                                                             
    TurnRight(u8),                                                                                                                                                            
    MoveForward(u8),                                                                                                                                                          
}

struct RobotOrders(String);

impl RobotOrders {
    fn new(source: impl Into<String>) -> Self {
        RobotOrders(source.into())
    }
}

impl Iterator for RobotOrders {
    type Item = Message;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Message> {
        self.0.chars().next()?;
        let order = self.0.remove(0);
        let n_digits = self.0.chars().take_while(char::is_ascii_digit).count();
        let mut number = self.0.clone();
        self.0 = number.split_off(n_digits);
        let number = number.parse().unwrap_or(1);

        Some(match order {
            'L' => Message::TurnLeft(number),
            'R' => Message::TurnRight(number),
            'M' => Message::MoveForward(number),
            _ => unimplemented!(),
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    use Message::*;
    let orders = RobotOrders::new("M3LMR2");
    let should_be = [MoveForward(3), TurnLeft(1), MoveForward(1), TurnRight(2)];

    assert!(orders.eq(should_be.iter().cloned()));
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but it seems the default when there is no number should be 1, not 0.

Comment: Thank you, this answer has a lot of things I can dig in.

Comment: Without copy, https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4332501936ad3e3ea875a7bd43cd2674&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: @Stargateur I cannot get what the `radix` stands for in your example.

Comment: @greg From [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_digit), "A 'radix' here is sometimes also called a 'base'. A radix of two indicates a binary number, a radix of ten, decimal, and a radix of sixteen, hexadecimal, to give some common values. Arbitrary radices are supported."